# The naive, formal, and critical phases of a scientific theory

Tags: philosophy-of-science

A long time ago, I read something about three stages in the development of a scientific or mathematical theory, namely the naive, the formal, and the critical phase. This appeared very natural to me, e.g. with respect to mathematical theories like set theory or category theory where people explicitly use the word "naive".

Later I tried to find out two who this goes back, and for a while I thought it must be an idea from Kuhn's "Structure of Scientific Revolutions", but he is not explicitly using these words I think?

Is there a well known work that makes this naive/formal/critical distinction explicit?

Comment: It's in Kuhn Structure of scientific revolutions

Comment: Hmm, just did a fulltext search for "naive" in "https://www.lri.fr/~mbl/Stanford/CS477/papers/Kuhn-SSR-2ndEd.pdf", and didn't find anything. So Kuhn doesn't seem to be using this exact word at least.

Comment: Ok it's not very exact the mapping. [Kuhn](https://web.colby.edu/continuingrevolutions/2016/11/07/kuhns-scientific-revolution/)      said (1) pre paradigm or pre science (corresponds to ur naive) (2) normal corresponds ur formal (3) anomaly & crisis corresponds ur critical

Comment: More similar to Lakatos' approach to the development of mathematics; see [Proofs and Refutations (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations).

Comment: There is something related by Tao: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_maturity#Progression